# Is there any way to invert the caret?

Tags: visual-studio, cursor

When programming in Visual Studio, the caret (i.e. the vertical line that shows where text will be inserted) is either a vertical line (when in insert mode) or a block (when in overwrite mode).

Is there anyway to make it the other way around?

I just like the block caret...reminds me of the 380Z that I first started programming on...

Comment: Back in the day of the 380Z the item marking the place where text was to be inserted was probably often called a caret, but today the item marking the place where text is to be inserted is more correctly called the cursor.  Today a [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) is this character `^`.

Comment: You understand that, in agreement with the comment by typoking, most people will assume that you are looking for caron (upside down ^), not reversing your cursor behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorSize = 100`

The value is a percentage size.  Default value is 25.

Comment: Obviously, add this to your $profile if you want it to be the default.

Comment: $Host what now? Where would you execute this? Or, are you talking Unix?

Comment: I would pay money that this was a PowerShell question.  Please ignore if it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, no it wasn't a powershell question. I've never used powershell - but if I can use that to change the standard caret - then that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. The vertical line in the VS editor sits between two characters, showing where the new character will be inserted. In insert mode, the block shows which character will be replaced. Nearly every development text editor I've used (many versions of Visual Studio, Delphi, VBA editor in Excel, etc) uses this convention. Swapping the modes just wouldn't make much sense.